# In Polymer 1.0 why does my vulcanized page not show in IE when using webcomponents-lite.js

Tags: polymer, vulcanize

I am trying to move to use webcomponents-lite.js, but have problems when vulcanizing it. I have boiled it down to the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js'></script>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html'>
</head>
<body>
    <paper-input></paper-input>
</body>
```

Which does not work in IE after being vulcanized

If I switch to

```
<script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js'></script>
```

it works

I am doing --inline-scripts --inline-css with version 1.14.0

It fails in the polymer part (I think) in a function

```
removeAttribute: function (name) {
    this.node.removeAttribute(name);
    this._distributeParent();
},
```

with: Object doesn't support property or method 'removeAttribute'

I must be doing something wrong in this somewhat simple example, but what is it?

Is there something that lite does not polyfill?

Thanks a lot

Cheers

Comment: I really just need any example out there of a site based on lite that works in IE .... then I'll be on track

Comment: I also ran into this bug today when using vulcanize and opening in IE11. My temporary workaround is to not use vulcanize. Hopefully they fix this in vulcanize since it's a very useful tool if it doesn't break your site!

Comment: Not using vulcanize is unfortunately not an option in my case as the site becomes unusable in all other browsers than Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest version of webcomponents ... woohoo

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue with polymer 1.2.0, can you tell me how do we fix this?